# Access denied when adding rule to Windows firewall (INetFwPolicy2) with C# from Core Middleware program

Tags: c#, permissions, windows-firewall, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm trying to add a rule to Windows firewall in .Net Core Middleware (httpHandler) written in C# . The code looks like this:

```
INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
 var rule = firewallPolicy.Rules.Item("IPBan_0"); 
 string[] addrs = rule.RemoteAddresses.ToString().Split(',');
 if (Array.IndexOf(addrs, $"{ip}/255.255.255.255") == -1)
 {
     rule.RemoteAddresses += $",{ip}/255.255.255.255";  <--  Error Here 
 }
```

I assume I have to give "something" elevated privileges but not sure if I can give them to this firewallPolicy or the whole program... which I'd like to avoid if I could. I tried specifying the admin user in this web's basic settings but that didn't help.

What do I need to do in order to get this working?

Comment: The user running this piece of code needs to be admin, which means that yes, the program must run with elevated rights

Comment: I went into this web application's basic settings and connected using the specific user, administrator but still get the error.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: The above code runs as part of a web server? That sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: Yes, it is a single app in the web server and I'm aware of the danger in that.  Still trying to think of other approaches.

Comment: Then you need to run the web server process with elevated permissions. Works, but is highly risky.

Comment: I changed the app pool for that web app to an admin user and it works.  Took it out of the web site and it still works.  So the only thing that's "exposed" is the single web app

Comment: PMF, if you want to answer, I'll accept it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the firewall rules requires elevated permissions - for very good reasons. When the code runs in a web server process, that web server needs to have elevated permission, which is independent from the rights the user might have on the served web page.

While it is possible to run a web server with admin rights, this is generally a bad idea, because it could make it easier for hackers to break into the server and take full control of it, so this should really only be used if there's no other way.